# Use different delimiters in Python or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, delimiter

I would like to save a nx3-array with `np.savetxt('out.dat', X, delimiter='-')`. Now comes the clue: Instead of using '-' between the columns I want a '-' between column 0 and 1, and a ';' between column 1 and 2:

```
1-4;6
2-5;7
3-6;8
```

Is there a fast an easy way to do this?

Kind regards

Comment: you can e.g. use the fmt parameter, like: `fmt='%i-%i;%i'`

Comment: thanks a lot, that does the job

Comment: @cel Good tip!  You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fmt` parameter to give a format string that is applied row-wise. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.arange(4*3).reshape(4, 3)
np.savetxt("arange.mat", M, fmt="%i-%i;%i")
```

`cat arange.mat` gives:

```
0-1;2
3-4;5
6-7;8
9-10;11
```